# Continuity of the conditional expectation

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, st.statistics

Consider the conditional expectation of $x$ given $y$,
$$
\mathbb{E}(x | y)
$$
where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ where $X, Y$ are Hilbert spaces (possibly infinite dimensional).

**Question :**
I am looking for conditions under which
$$
    \mathbb{E}(x | \cdot ) : Y \to X
$$
is a continuous function.

I'll give some simple examples to illustrate the problem:

**Example 1:** Assume $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$, let $x$ have a gaussian prior with mean 0 and unit variance and let $y$ be gaussian with mean $x$ and unit variance. [In this case we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error#Linear_MMSE_estimator_for_linear_observation_process)
$$
\mathbb{E}(x | y)
=
\frac{y}{2}
$$
which is continuous.

**Example 2:** Assume $X = Y = \ell_2$. Let $x$ have a gaussian prior with $x_i \sim N(0, 1/i)$ and let $y_i ~ \sim N(x_i / i, 1 / i^3)$. In this case we have
$$
[\mathbb{E}(x | y)]_i = 
\left(
\frac{1}{i}
i^3
\frac{1}{i} + 
i
\right)^{-1}
\frac{1}{i}
i^3
y_i
=
\frac{i}{2}
y_i
$$
This is a linear operator, but unbounded, hence $\mathbb{E}(x | \cdot)$ is not continuous.

Comment: Your question is not well posed. Apparently, $x$ is a fixed random variable with values in $X$. But what is then $y\mapsto E(x|y)$?

Comment: I was sloppy on the notation to save some space. To be more strict, the idea is that $X/Y$ are $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{Y}$ valued random variables and hence $E(X|Y)$ is an $\mathcal{X}$ valued random variable which is a function of a $\mathcal{Y}$ valued random variable. Thus the function I'm looking for is thus more strictly $y \to E(X|Y=y)$.